# Spark SQL Dataframe- java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException error

Tags: java, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

Using spark java I have created dataframe on comma delimiter source file. In sourcefile if last column contains blank value then its throwing `arrayindexoutofbound` error. Below is sample data and code. is there any way I can handle this error because there is lot of chance getting blank values in last column. In below sample data 4th row causing issue.

Sample Data:

```
1,viv,chn,34
2,man,gnt,56
3,anu,pun,22
4,raj,bang,*
```

Code:

```
        JavaRDD<String> dataQualityRDD = spark.sparkContext().textFile(inputFile, 1).toJavaRDD();
        String schemaString = schemaColumns;
        List<StructField> fields = new ArrayList<>();
        for (String fieldName : schemaString.split(" ")) {
          StructField field = DataTypes.createStructField(fieldName, DataTypes.StringType, true);
          fields.add(field);
        }
        StructType schema = DataTypes.createStructType(fields);

        JavaRDD<Row> rowRDD = dataQualityRDD.map((Function<String, Row>) record -> { 
                   // String[] attributes = record.split(attributes[0], attributes[1].trim());
                   Object[] items = record.split(fileSplit);

                   // return RowFactory.create(attributes[0], attributes[1].trim()); 
                           return RowFactory.create(items);
                 }); 


        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I used spark 2.0 and was able to read the csv without any exception:

```
        SparkSession spark = SparkSession.builder().config("spark.master", "local").getOrCreate();
    JavaSparkContext jsc = JavaSparkContext.fromSparkContext(spark.sparkContext());

    JavaRDD<Row> csvRows = spark.read().csv("resources/csvwithnulls.csv").toJavaRDD();

    StructType schema = DataTypes.createStructType(
            new StructField[] { new StructField("id", DataTypes.StringType, false, Metadata.empty()),
                    new StructField("fname", DataTypes.StringType, false, Metadata.empty()),
                    new StructField("lname", DataTypes.StringType, false, Metadata.empty()),
                    new StructField("age", DataTypes.StringType, false, Metadata.empty()) });

    Dataset<Row> newCsvRows = spark.createDataFrame(csvRows, schema);
    newCsvRows.show();
```

Used exactly the rows you have and it worked fine: see the output:

[image]

[image]

Comment: ref: https://medium.com/@mrpowers/sparks-treatment-of-empty-strings-and-null-values-in-csv-files-80748893451f

Comment: Based on the source file I will be passing sql query which dynamically generates by another job.sql query will help me to know column information with error records.

Comment: I am sorry, if I misunderstood your question. But, in either case, you can create a Dataset like above and then pass in your query which you already have in one of the params I think? Any further transformations/actions can be performed by registering the dataset as a temp table? So, in a nutshell you have to maintain source file to query+other params map or something?

Comment: Thanks!!on top of the temp table I should pass the query but some of the files will not have header information.in that scenario my job will get fail due to column name mismatch.Based on the DDL dynamically ill create sql query..if there is no header then how can I handle this?

Comment: val b=spark.read.csv("/user/dfgs/spark_test/").toDF("name", "address"," id", "date")..other than thius is there any way I can map columnnames

Comment: Updated the answer, so assume the that csv doesn't have a schema then you can read that as a JavaRDD<Row> and then apply a schema explicitly to create Dataset. Hope this helps.