# Spark Dataframe - java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 26 while writing to S3

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, parquet

I am trying to read some data from a snowflake table using Spark-Snowflake connector and write the data to S3 after performing some transformations. But I am seeing the error `java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 26` when the line `df.write.partitionBy(partitionColumn).mode(SaveMode.Append).parquet(s3Destination)` is encountered.

Below is the full stacktrace:

```
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 26
    at org.apache.spark.sql.types.StructType.apply(StructType.scala:414)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.optimizer.ObjectSerializerPruning$$anonfun$apply$4.$anonfun$applyOrElse$3(objects.scala:224)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike.$anonfun$map$1(TraversableLike.scala:238)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:392)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike.map(TraversableLike.scala:238)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike.map$(TraversableLike.scala:231)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.map(List.scala:298)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.optimizer.ObjectSerializerPruning$$anonfun$apply$4.applyOrElse(objects.scala:223)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.optimizer.ObjectSerializerPruning$$anonfun$apply$4.applyOrElse(objects.scala:211)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.$anonfun$transformDown$1(TreeNode.scala:328)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.CurrentOrigin$.withOrigin(TreeNode.scala:74)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.transformDown(TreeNode.scala:328)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.LogicalPlan.org$apache$spark$sql$catalyst$plans$logical$AnalysisHelper$$super$transformDown(LogicalPlan.scala:29)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.AnalysisHelper.transformDown(AnalysisHelper.scala:171)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.AnalysisHelper.transformDown$(AnalysisHelper.scala:169)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.LogicalPlan.transformDown(LogicalPlan.scala:29)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.LogicalPlan.transformDown(LogicalPlan.scala:29)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.$anonfun$transformDown$3(TreeNode.scala:333)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.applyFunctionIfChanged$1(TreeNode.scala:387)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.$anonfun$mapChildren$1(TreeNode.scala:423)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.mapProductIterator(TreeNode.scala:255)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.mapChildren(TreeNode.scala:421)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.mapChildren(TreeNode.scala:369)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.transformDown(TreeNode.scala:333)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.LogicalPlan.org$apache$spark$sql$catalyst$plans$logical$AnalysisHelper$$super$transformDown(LogicalPlan.scala:29)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.AnalysisHelper.transformDown(AnalysisHelper.scala:171)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.AnalysisHelper.transformDown$(AnalysisHelper.scala:169)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.LogicalPlan.transformDown(LogicalPlan.scala:29)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.LogicalPlan.transformDown(LogicalPlan.scala:29)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.$anonfun$transformDown$3(TreeNode.scala:333)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.applyFunctionIfChanged$1(TreeNode.scala:387)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.$anonfun$mapChildren$1(TreeNode.scala:423)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.mapProductIterator(TreeNode.scala:255)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.mapChildren(TreeNode.scala:421)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.mapChildren(TreeNode.scala:369)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.transformDown(TreeNode.scala:333)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.LogicalPlan.org$apache$spark$sql$catalyst$plans$logical$AnalysisHelper$$super$transformDown(LogicalPlan.scala:29)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.AnalysisHelper.transformDown(AnalysisHelper.scala:171)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.AnalysisHelper.transformDown$(AnalysisHelper.scala:169)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.LogicalPlan.transformDown(LogicalPlan.scala:29)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.LogicalPlan.transformDown(LogicalPlan.scala:29)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.transform(TreeNode.scala:317)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.optimizer.ObjectSerializerPruning$.apply(objects.scala:211)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.optimizer.ObjectSerializerPruning$.apply(objects.scala:121)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.rules.RuleExecutor.$anonfun$execute$2(RuleExecutor.scala:216)
    at scala.collection.IndexedSeqOptimized.foldLeft(IndexedSeqOptimized.scala:60)
    at scala.collection.IndexedSeqOptimized.foldLeft$(IndexedSeqOptimized.scala:68)
    at scala.collection.mutable.WrappedArray.foldLeft(WrappedArray.scala:38)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.rules.RuleExecutor.$anonfun$execute$1(RuleExecutor.scala:213)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.rules.RuleExecutor.$anonfun$execute$1$adapted(RuleExecutor.scala:205)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:392)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.rules.RuleExecutor.execute(RuleExecutor.scala:205)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.rules.RuleExecutor.$anonfun$executeAndTrack$1(RuleExecutor.scala:183)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.QueryPlanningTracker$.withTracker(QueryPlanningTracker.scala:107)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.rules.RuleExecutor.executeAndTrack(RuleExecutor.scala:183)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.$anonfun$optimizedPlan$1(QueryExecution.scala:87)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.QueryPlanningTracker.measurePhase(QueryPlanningTracker.scala:192)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.$anonfun$executePhase$1(QueryExecution.scala:163)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.withActive(SparkSession.scala:772)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.executePhase(QueryExecution.scala:163)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.optimizedPlan$lzycompute(QueryExecution.scala:84)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.optimizedPlan(QueryExecution.scala:84)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.$anonfun$writePlans$4(QueryExecution.scala:243)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.QueryPlan$.append(QueryPlan.scala:487)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.writePlans(QueryExecution.scala:243)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.toString(QueryExecution.scala:260)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.org$apache$spark$sql$execution$QueryExecution$$explainString(QueryExecution.scala:216)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.explainString(QueryExecution.scala:195)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.executeQuery$1(SQLExecution.scala:102)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.$anonfun$withNewExecutionId$6(SQLExecution.scala:135)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.QueryPlanningTracker$.withTracker(QueryPlanningTracker.scala:107)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withTracker(SQLExecution.scala:232)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.$anonfun$withNewExecutionId$5(SQLExecution.scala:135)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withSQLConfPropagated(SQLExecution.scala:253)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.$anonfun$withNewExecutionId$1(SQLExecution.scala:134)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.withActive(SparkSession.scala:772)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withNewExecutionId(SQLExecution.scala:68)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.runCommand(DataFrameWriter.scala:989)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.saveToV1Source(DataFrameWriter.scala:438)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.saveInternal(DataFrameWriter.scala:415)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.save(DataFrameWriter.scala:293)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.parquet(DataFrameWriter.scala:874)
    at spark.ExportEvents$.writeToS3(ExportEvents.scala:315)
    at spark.ExportEvents$.$anonfun$processIncrementalLoad$1(ExportEvents.scala:257)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.map(List.scala:286)
    at spark.ExportEvents$.processIncrementalLoad(ExportEvents.scala:185)
    at spark.ExportEvents$.main(ExportEvents.scala:75)
    at spark.ExportEvents.main(ExportEvents.scala)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.JavaMainApplication.start(SparkApplication.scala:52)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$runMain(SparkSubmit.scala:959)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.doRunMain$1(SparkSubmit.scala:180)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:203)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.doSubmit(SparkSubmit.scala:90)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$$anon$2.doSubmit(SparkSubmit.scala:1038)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:1047)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)
```

I am not sure why this is happening and how to resolve this. As a part of my transformations I am modifying a column name and it's changed into lower case where as all other columns are in uppercase. I am not sure if this is causing the issue as I believe parquet and spark are case insensitive by default.

I am using `Spark 3.1.1` and `spark-snowflake_2.12`. Any help would be appreciated, thank you.

Comment: hi, perhaps might be of interest https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46779409/spark-sql-dataframe-java-lang-arrayindexoutofboundsexception-error

Comment: @jspcal I am loading from snowflake and my last column is not null or blank.